# Gmail DMARC Validation is Trashing Contact Form Messages from Yahoo and AOL Email Accounts

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace

We recently realized that Gmail has silently been trashing messages sent to us via our contact form from addresses ending in `@yahoo.com` and `@aol.com` for the past 2 months due to [DMARC Validation settings that Yahoo and AOL have recently set](http://sendgrid.com/blog/update-yahoos-dmarc-policy/).

The contact form on our website sends to our Gmail account (setup with Google Apps for Domains) with a `From` header of the person sending the email.

For several years this has worked splendidly but now Gmail has silently begun trashing these unauthenticated emails.

Is there a way to disable DMARC validation so that Gmail still delivers these messages to our inbox rather than silently deleting them? They don't even end up in the spam or trash folders; they are just never delivered!

We tried setting a `Reply-To` header instead and setting `From` to be an address from our own domain but unfortunately Gmail doesn't appear to honor this and replies were often accidentally just being sent to ourselves and not our customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by going back to the `Reply-To` workaround and tricking Gmail into using it via the responses from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957965/gmail-does-not-detect-the-reply-to-field

> Gmail ignores the reply-to when the From is one of your configured send-as addresses in gmail. I don't know why.

So ultimately the problem there was that we were sending from `contact@ourdomain.com` to `contact@ourdomain.com` so the `Reply-To` was ignored.